# cannot convert type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange' to 'double?'

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

```
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    ExcelWorksheet sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    for (int rowNum = 2; rowNum <= sheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
        var wsRow = sheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, sheet.Dimension.End.Column];
        DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
        {
            if (wsRow[rowNum, 12] == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            row["model_number"] = wsRow[rowNum, 1];
            row["product_name"] = wsRow[rowNum, 2];
            row["enemy"] = wsRow[rowNum, 9];

            try
            {
                row["regular_price"] = wsRow[rowNum, 3] == null ? DBNull.Value : (double?)wsRow[rowNum, 3] == 0 ? DBNull.Value : wsRow[rowNum, 3];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                row["regular_price"] = 0;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

on the last line written to excel I get the error

> cannot convert type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange' to 'double?'

Comment: Without looking into much detail: The error says, you are trying to convert an ExcelRange into a double - now all you need to do is take the value of a single cell instead and converting to a double should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual cell value, you want to use the `.Value` property of the `ExcelRange` like this:

```
(double?)wsRow[rowNum, 3].Value == 0
```

otherwise you are trying to cast an `ExcelRange` to a double, as the error explains.

The same goes for your other lines.  Like

```
row["model_number"] = wsRow[rowNum, 1];
```

you probably really want

```
row["model_number"] = wsRow[rowNum, 1].Value;
```

Might need to do some type checks unless you are confident the data in the excel is "clean".